# Alphabetic Footnote Marks that (automatically) omit the letters 'j' and 'w'

Tags: footnotes, counters

I am trying to duplicate the footnote style from a book where the footnote marks are the letters of the alphabet—but the footnote omits the letters 'j' and 'w'.

The kludge I have worked out involves manually resetting the footnote counter using `\setcounter{footnote}{#}` to skip the letters.

I haven't been able to find a package that does this, and have no idea how to do it myself.

Here is what I have.

```
\documentclass[11pt, nomath]{amsbook}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}    %   footnotes a, b, c,
%\makeatletter                          %   reset footnote counter
%\@addtoreset{footnote}{section}            %   at each section break
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
The\footnote{something} quick\footnote{something} brown\footnote{something} fox had\footnote{something} a\footnote{something} short\footnote{something} bushy\footnote{something} tail\footnote{something} that\footnote{something} %
\setcounter{footnote}{10}%
looked\footnote{something} like\footnote{something} something\footnote{something} you\footnote{something} might\footnote{something} have\footnote{something} gotten\footnote{something} from\footnote{something} the\footnote{something} Fuller\footnote{something} Brush\footnote{something} Man,\footnote{something} %
\setcounter{footnote}{23}%
back\footnote{something} when they still came\footnote{something} house-to-house\footnote{something} %
\setcounter{footnote}{0}%
selling\footnote{something} their goods.\footnote{something}
\end{document}
```

---

I have posted a separate question about ['looping' the footnote marks from 'z' back to 'a'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452865/alphabetic-footnote-marks-to-roll-over-from-z-to-a-automatically).

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the way the regular `\alph` is defined (from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\def\alph#1{\expandafter\@alph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@alph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or
    y\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
```

Each element of the alphabet is specified in sequence as part of an `\ifcase`...`\fi`. 
You can define your "own alphabet" using the same technique, thereby omitting `j` and `w` (reducing your 26-letter alphabet down to 24):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\cyclenojwalph{footnote}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nojwalph}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or 
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or x\or
    y\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\cyclenojwalph}[1]{\ifnum\value{#1}=24 \setcounter{#1}{0}\fi\nojwalph{\value{#1}}}

\begin{document}

When\footnote{something} the\footnote{something} quick\footnote{something} brown\footnote{something} fox--which\footnote{something} 
had\footnote{something} a\footnote{something} short\footnote{something} bushy\footnote{something} tail\footnote{something} 
that\footnote{something} looked\footnote{something} like\footnote{something} something\footnote{something} you\footnote{something} 
might\footnote{something} have\footnote{something} gotten\footnote{something} from\footnote{something} the\footnote{something} 
Fuller\footnote{something} brush\footnote{something} man\footnote{something} back\footnote{something} when\footnote{something} 
they\footnote{something} %
came\footnote{something} house\footnote{something} to\footnote{something} house\footnote{something} selling\footnote{something} 
their\footnote{something} goods---jumped\footnote{something} over\footnote{something} the\footnote{something} fat\footnote{something} 
and\footnote{something} lazy\footnote{something} calico\footnote{something} cat,\footnote{something} a\footnote{something} 
little\footnote{something} dog\footnote{something} which\footnote{something} had\footnote{something} been\footnote{something} 
yapping\footnote{something} at\footnote{something} a\footnote{something} squirrel\footnote{something} laughed\footnote{something} 
to\footnote{something} %
see\footnote{something} such\footnote{something} a\footnote{something} sight:\footnote{something} and\footnote{something} 
the\footnote{something} dish\footnote{something} ran\footnote{something} away\footnote{something} with\footnote{something} 
the\footnote{something} spoon\footnote{something} as\footnote{something} the\footnote{something} cow\footnote{something} 
jumped\footnote{something} over\footnote{something} the\footnote{something} moon.\footnote{something}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the original `\alph` definition/command. The whole kit-n-caboodle is up and working in my actual file. I've also added a reference from my related question to this answer that incorporates both answers (using @marmot original cycle command).